# Android: How to share files on a local network?

Tags: android, wifi-direct, file-sharing

I want to create application which can share files through wifi similar to [Xender](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cn.xender)/[Superbeam](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.majedev.superbeam). 
I don't want to rely on router or some other hotspot.
I want to create new connection from one device and other devices should able to find and connect.
How can I achieve any sample code or link will help.

Comment: It will be great if you share some existing code that you have already tried.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try using wifi Direct .
Here is the documentation [Wifi P2p](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html)
You can also try out the demo by importing sample project. 
Also try out this extension of [wifi p2p demo](https://github.com/ahmontero/wifi-direct-demo) 
Even Superbeam uses wifi direct as a fallback.